# Вывод данных разделенных символом из базы

Tags: c#, база-данных

Есть база данных, которая содержит в себе данные в следующем виде(данные случайные):

```
{Id}{InitialData}{CorrectResult}
| 1 |0,3/0,1/5/0,7|5/3,5/4/7,5|
| 2 |0,5/1/9/0,235|6/6,5/5/2,5|
| 3 |3,3/0,1/3/5,7|3/3,3/2/1,5|
```

Как вывести данные столбца initial data в DGV в разные столбцы, разделяя их "/"? Например 0,3 в первую ячейку dgv, 0,1 во вторую и т.д.

Comment: *Есть база данных* Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию. *содержит в себе данные в следующем виде* Покажите структуру таблицы (её CREATE TABLE). *Как вывести данные ... Например* Покажите полный желаемый ответ на именно этих данных.

Comment: [How to: Parse Strings Using String.Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string rowData = "| 1 |0,3/0,1/5/0,7|5/3,5/4/7,5|";
            var columnData = rowData.Split(new[] { '|' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);// разбиваем строку по |
            // получаем массив стрингов 
            //columnData[0]=1
            //columnData[1]=0,3/0,1/5/0,7
            //columnData[2]=5/3,5/4/7,5

            var content1 = columnData[1].Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            //резуьтат работы :

            //content1[0] = 0,3
            //content1[1] = 0,1
            //content1[2] = 5
            //content1[3] = 0,7

            var content2 = columnData[2].Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            //резуьтат работы :

            //content2[0] = 5
            //content2[1] = 3,5
            //content2[2] = 4
            //content2[3] = 7,5

            // после этого добавляете эти элементы в DataGridview
```

Comment: Вод код который обработает вашу строку

Comment: Примерно разобрался, вот мой код: string sqlQueryInitial = "select InitialData from Variant where IDVariant="+var; SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryInitial,sc); SqlDataReader rd = cmd1.ExecuteReader(); Как мне все это вывести в первую строку DGV, учитывая разделитель. Попробовал так, не получилось: var resultSqlQuery = rd.GetString(0).Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); dataGridView1.Rows[0].SetValues(resultSqlQuery);

Comment: `resultSqlQuery` это массив который содержит ваши сторки их  и передавайте `rowData=resultSqlQuery[i]` создайте метод который будет принимать String и заполнять все в дата грид